# Why iPhone Safari 15.1 does not loads in webM

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, mp4, webm

Based on the news, iPhone and Safari should support webM. But it does not load in. Do you have any idea why?

Shall I use mp4?

Comment: Did you test with iOS 15?

Comment: I think they only added WebM audio, not video. See https://9to5mac.com/2021/08/10/apple-adding-webm-audio-codec-support-to-safari-with-ios-15/#disqus_thread

Comment: yes, tested with iOS 15.1

Comment: And `WebM Web Audio` is enabled in the advanced settings?